# How to print a list of tuples with no brackets in Python

Tags: python, list, printing, tuples

I'm looking for a way to print elements from a tuple with no brackets.

Here is my tuple:

```
mytuple = [(1.0,),(25.34,),(2.4,),(7.4,)]
```

I converted this to a list to make it easier to work with

```
mylist = list(mytuple)
```

Then I did the following

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item.strip())
```

But I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Which is strange because I thought I converted to a list?

What I expect to see as the final result is something like:

```
1.0,
25.34,
2.4,
7.4
```

or

```
1.0, ,23.43, ,2.4, ,7.4
```

Comment: you actually want those double commas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`mytuple` is already a list (a list of tuples), so calling `list()` on it does nothing.

`(1.0,)` is a tuple with one item. You can't call string functions on it (like you tried). They're for string types.

To print each item in your list of tuples, just do:

```
for item in mytuple:
    print str(item[0]) + ','
```

Or:

```
print ', ,'.join([str(i[0]) for i in mytuple])
# 1.0, ,25.34, ,2.4, ,7.4
```

Comment: would `print ', ,'.join(map(str, mytuple))` do the same ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Nope as we need `i[0] for i` and not `i for i`

Answer (score 20):

You can do it like this as well:

```
mytuple = (1,2,3)
print str(mytuple)[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mytuple = [(1.0,),(25.34,),(2.4,),(7.4,)]
for item in mytuple:
    print(*item) # *==> unpacking
```

Answer (score 1):

I iterate through the list tuples, than I iterate through the 'items' of the tuples.

```
my_tuple_list = [(1.0,),(25.34,),(2.4,),(7.4,)]

for a_tuple in my_tuple_list:  # iterates through each tuple
    for item in a_tuple:  # iterates through each tuple items
        print item
```

result:

```
1.0
25.34
2.4
7.4
```

to get exactly the result you mentioned above you can always add

```
print item + ','
```

Answer (score 0):

One can generalize to any complex structure with use of recursion:

```
def flatten(o):
    if not isinstance(o, (list, tuple, dict)):
        return str(o)
    elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
        return "\n".join(flatten(e) for e in o)
    elif isinstance(o, (dict)):
        return "\n".join(e + ": " + flatten(o[e]) for e in o)
```

Example:

```
>>> flatten((1, [21, {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'}], 3))
'1, 21, a: aaa\nb: bbb, 3'
```