# How can I take off the parenthesis when I output a tuple in python?

Tags: python

```py
exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
print(f'The examination will start from {exam_st_date}')
```

The output I'm getting is the examination will start from `(11,12,2014)`. How can I get rid of these parenthesis?

Comment: [How to print a list of tuples with no brackets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112735/how-to-print-a-list-of-tuples-with-no-brackets-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
print(f'The examination will start from {str(exam_st_date).strip("()"))}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is really simple and helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand why it's printing out parentheses. It's because `(11,12,2014)` is a tuple. My suggestion is either use a correct `datetime` variable and `datetime.strftime` or you can simply just format the tuple using `str.join`

```
print(f'The examination will start from {",".join(exam_st_date)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the tuple `exam_st_date` to a string and remove its first and last characters:

```
print(f'The examination will start from {str(exam_st_date)[1:-1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:
exam_st_date = (11, 12, 2014)
print(f'The examination will start from {exam_st_date[0], exam_st_date[1], exam_st_date[2]}')